# Node.js Restify send response when value changed

Tags: node.js, caching, response, forward, restify

I have a nodejs+restify server set up. It is used for an online ordering api that accepts online orders from different vendors and forwards them down to the relevant store and pos terminal.

This is working fine for most of the vendors. I am having a problem with a specific vendor that wants to post to my server and I should only reply with http.200 when the order has been processed at the store. This takes about 5 seconds during a busy time period.

The process currently works as follows: 
 1. Vendor Posts Transaction to API. 
 2. API writes order to database
 3. Store checks in at regular intervals for new orders and downloads if exist.
 4. Store updates order status to completed once processed.
 5. Api updates order status with vendor.

What I want to achieve is that the vendor will post to /orders/{orderid} but I will not send a response back until the store has posted to /status/{orderid}

I tried creating a key value store with the orderid as key and response object has value, but I can't seem to send a response using this method.

Code:
What is was:

```
//Vendor posts new order
//Body contains json data { 'orderid' : 'xxxx', 'storeid': 'ABC', 'lines' : []}
server.post('/order/:vendor',function(req,res,next){
    //write order to database on success call res.send(200);
});

//Vendor queries order status
server.get('/orderstatus/:orderid',function(req,res,next){
    //read order status from database on return result call res.send({'orderid' : 'xxxx', 'status': 5});
}

//Store checks for orders
server.get('/store/orders/:storeid',function(req,res,next){
    // get all new orders (status = 0) and return with res.send({'orders': [{ 'orderid' : 'xxxx', 'storeid': 'ABC', 'lines' : []}]});
}

//Store Updates order status
server.put('/orderstatus/:vendor/:orderid/:status',function(req,res,next){
    /*update order with new status. if vendor requires post from this api then use client to
     update status with vendor. call res.rend(200);
    */
}

//THIS IS FOR NEW CLIENT
var ordersforyyy =[]
//changed Vendor post to:
server.post('/order/:vendor',function(req,res,next){
    if (req.params.vendor === 'yyy') {
        //write order to database. then:
        ordersforyyy.push({orderid : req.body.orderid, response: res});
        //Do not send response 200
    }
    else {//write order to database on success call res.send(200);}
});

server.put('/orderstatus/:vendor/:orderid/:status',function(req,res,next){
    if (req.params.vendor === 'yyy') {
          var response = orders.filter(function(item){ return item.orderid === req.params.orderid; })[0];
          response.response.send(200);
    }
    else {
    /*update order with new status. if vendor requires post from this api then use client to
     update status with vendor. call res.rend(200);
    */}
}
```

Comment: It's really hard to understand with just words mate. Please post some code... Does the vendors post to your API and get a response back if the order was processed correctly or are they "checking back" at regular intervals to see if the order has been processed yet? I really don't understand the whole workflow here

Comment: I was obviously very tired when I tried to do this. Got it working with caching the response object.

Comment: All the vendors post to my IP and get a response back immediately. Some of them check back regularly for status updates and some I post to them when the status updates. The vendor I had a problem with, wanted to post but not get an http response back until the order was processed at the store

Comment: So everything's working as it should now?

Comment: yes. Sorry for wasting time. When searching the array I did not include the [0] to return the first order matching id, so it returned another array instead of the object.

Comment: Time is overrated ;-)

Comment: Sometimes it helps to just write down a problem instead of banging your head against it.

Answer (score 0):

When searching the array I did not include the [0] to return the first order matching id, so it returned another array instead of the object